# ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models `Project` and `UrlList`. A project `:has_many` url_list and a url_list `:belongs_to` project.

Now I have array for project id's `all_projects = [1,2,5,8,16]`. I want to retrieve all the records from `url_list` where `project_id` is one of those from `all_projects` array. How do I write code for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass an array as value for an attribute to `where` method:

```
all_projects = [1, 2, 5, 8, 16]   
url_lists = UrlList.where(:project_id => all_projects)
```

It'll generate SQL query like that:

```
SELECT `url_lists`.* FROM `url_lists` WHERE `project_id`.`user_id` IN (1, 2, 5, 8, 16)
```

Comment: I know it didn't break anything, but I still considered it a typo since I guess most people would expect that variable name to at least be properly spelled ;)